# MFA for AWS workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

We have installed free radius server and configured MFA for AWS workspace authentication.
after 30 days, now if we enter any code in MFA filed it is authenticating. any suggestions?

Not to allow login without exact code